# Multiple characters are displayed per key press

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, language

**I'm using an ASUS X550L running Win10x64 Turkish language.**

Recently I installed the English (US) language pack through `Settings/Time&Language/Region&Language: Add a language` option. However after some time I decided to remove it. Afterwards my keyboard started acting up.

Most keys work fine (including the Turkish keys). However some display additional characters. Pressing `E` yields `E3` or `e3` (it alternates, very oddly). Pressing `H` yields an always capital `H67`.

The keyboard had no issue before playing around with the language options.

---

**What I've tried thus far (none worked):**

- Revert the driver to a previous version.
- Remove the driver, and restart the PC. Windows reinstalled the default driver.
- Remove the driver and install the official driver from ASUS.
- Reinstall the English language (didn't work, so I removed it again).
- Try selecting different keyboard mappings (TUK QWERTY, ENG QWERTY, etc..)

Oddly, the USB keyboard I plugged in works perfectly fine. Whatever issue is present, it is only affecting the embedded keyboard.

---

**What I plan on trying:**

- Try the keyboard in safe mode (different drivers are loaded, right?)
- Run a USB booter (e.g. a Linux distro) and see if that works
- Worse case scenario: format

Being a programmer, I must admit that I'm not too familiar with these sorts of issues. Any tips would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Sounds like a mechanical/electrical issue in the keyboard. Did it get wet or dirty?

Comment: @Aganju There was no physical damage. The issue began immediately after removing the English language pack.